# How to redistributie compiled proprietar software for Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, dependencies

I want to redistribute my software as binary (Linux) package. But AFAIK where are a lot of difficulties, related to "dependency/dll hell".

What is common suggestions in this case? (except redistributing source codes)

1. link all statically?
2. declare support of only main dists (Ubuntu for example)?
3. Create Windows application and execute is under Wine?

My goal is to make my app working on most platforms without resolving any dependency conflicts and w/o recompiling it on designated machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest supporting only a subset of Linux distributions (e.g., Red Hat 6.5, some Ubuntu LTS, etc.) and build packages for each of these separately. It takes care of the dependencies.